# How to Check for variable value change in BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How i can get to know that variable value got changed dynamically.
As in AngularJS, we use `$watch` to know that variable/obj/array value get changed?

How we can get to know in BackboneJS.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [backbone listen to object changes in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093419/backbone-listen-to-object-changes-in-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable is a property of a Backbone model, than you can use `listenTo` -- http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

For example:

```
myView.listenTo(object, 'change:variable', callback)
```